# myRange function giving output of None. Why is this?

Tags: python, list

I am to create a function called myRange that behaves like range. This is for class and the instructions tell me to use Python's help for range but I am not understanding it at all. I am a complete greenhorn with Python. Please do not provide modules or methods.

```
def myRange(stop,start=None,step=None):
    outputList = []
    if stop == 0:
        start= 0
        stop = start
        step = 1

   

    
    
        return()





print(myRange(10))
```

I am expecting just this portion to give the output range of 10 displayed in a list.

Comment: Your function does nothing really. Seems like you should read a [Python beginners guide](https://www.python.org/about/gettingstarted/) first. ;)

Comment: What do you want your function to return?

Comment: The function has `return()`, which returns an empty tuple.  But it seems like you actually intended it to return something else.

Comment: Your function does 'something' if `stop == 0`. What does it do if `stop` is not zero, for example what if `stop` is actually `10`? What does a function that does nothing (and doesn't return anything explicitly) return?

Comment: `range` is not a function; it's a *type*. When you call it, you get back an instance of `range`, not something else.

Comment: @JohnGordon stop is 10, so it doesn't go into the if, and thus falls off the end and by default returning None... so much wrong here that I do think Cpt.Hook's suggestion is most useful.

Comment: As mentioned, `range` is a type and for instance `range(3)` is a class instance. `iter(range(3))` is a type `_range_iterator`. Neither of these things are lists. The first will test whether a value is in range and will return the iterator. The second is a generator that keeps emitting values in range until done. Simply writing a function will not be the same as `range`.

Comment: If you are expecting the list `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`, you're going to have to build it yourself and return it. All you've done so far is created an *empty* list. (`range` *used* to be a function that returned a list, in Python 2, but as such it also had to build the list that it returned. There's nothing magical about simply acknowledging the arguments passed to the function.)

Answer (score 0):

```py
# define a function called 'myRange' which takes 3 arguments,
# stop, start and step, where start and step default to None
def myRange(stop,start=None,step=None):

    # set the value of outputList to an empty list
    outputList = []

    # if stop is 0, do this block of code below
    if stop == 0:
        # set start to 0
        start= 0
        # set stop to 0 (this is a little
        # redundant as we already know stop is 0 at this point)
        stop = start

        # set step to 1
        step = 1

        # return an empty Tuple
        return()


print(myRange(10))
```

So you've definitely made a start and have some code down and running and this is always a huge milestone. It'll just take some figuring out and then I'm sure you'll get it. As you don't want specific code, here are some pointers:

1. What do you want the function to return? Right now it doesn't return anything. `range` in python returns a sequence of numbers, from `start` to `stop`, counting up by `step`. It goes up by `1` by default and starts at `0` by default
2. How would you describe the instructions for a human to perform this action? This can help you figure out what the code needs to do
3. The code indented under an if statement will only be run if that if statement is true

Hopefully that'll get you going in the right direction. Happy to help some more if you get stuck

Comment: This really helped progress my thought process on how to approach this problem and more. Thank you so very much for your clear explanation :)

Comment: @DevinS. I'm really glad to hear that this has helped - let me know if you need any assistance. Happy to help. If you're happy with this answer, you can accept it.